# Using Eventmachine http request in a Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine, sidekiq

So lets say I have a sidekiq process that sends off a http post request that I don't want to wait for. I don't want this to be a blocker on the speed of the workers.

One idea I have is to use this simple sample code for EventMachine Http Request

```
  EventMachine.run do
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://www.example.com").post :options => {...}
    http.callback do
      puts "got a response"
      puts http.response
      EventMachine.stop
    end
    puts "worker finished"
  end
```

so lets assume my worker process finishes before the callback is called. What will happen here?  does this mean the pointer to the call back will fail? I'd like to understand the flow of control here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need:

1. You want to **utilize CPU**
   Sidekiq workers are very lightweight. You can run more of them to utilize CPU while waiting responce.
2. You want workers to **finish faster**.
   You can enqueue each request to be proccessed by different worker. It will be like next_tick() in EM. 
   I'm excited about Sidekiq and Celluloid because it changes the way we think. http://www.slideshare.net/KyleDrake/hybrid-concurrency-patterns?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: Thanks, I like sidekiq too but running into issues with workers dying with no error. I think it may be related to non thread safe code but on first look it appears to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `EventMachine.run` block will not return until you call `EventMachine.stop`. So, on your case, the worker won't finish without the callback being run.

Comment: So is there any way I can do this which will allow the worker to finish and still asynchronously post off the http request.

Comment: This will be the behavior of your example, it's just that it will output "worker finished" before it finishes, because your `puts` is inside the `run` block.